# Ruby - calling constructor without arguments & removal of new line characters

Tags: ruby, constructor

I have written down a sample program and I don't understand the following:

1. Why constructor without any arguments are not called in Ruby?
2. How do we access the class variable outside the class's definition?
3. Why does it always append newline characters at the end of the string? How do we strip it?

Code:

```
class Employee
    attr_reader :empid
    attr_writer :empid
    attr_writer :name
    def name
        return @name.upcase
    end
    attr_accessor :salary
    @@employeeCount = 0
    def initiaze()
        @@employeeCount += 1
        puts ("Initialize called!")
    end
    def getCount
        return @@employeeCount
    end
end

anEmp = Employee.new
print ("Enter new employee name: ")
anEmp.name = gets()
print ("Enter #{anEmp.name}'s employee ID: ")
anEmp.empid = gets()
print ("Enter salary for #{anEmp.name}: ")
anEmp.salary = gets()
theEmpName = anEmp.name.split.join("\n")
theEmpID = anEmp.empid.split.join("\n")
theEmpSalary = anEmp.salary.split.join("\n")
anEmp = Employee.new()
anEmp = Employee.new()
theCount = anEmp.getCount
puts ("New employee #{theEmpName} with employee ID #{theEmpID} has been enrolled, welcome to hell! You have been paid as low as $ #{theEmpSalary}")
puts ("Total number of employees created = #{theCount}")
```

Output:

```
Enter new employee name: Lionel Messi
Enter LIONEL MESSI
's employee ID: 10
Enter salary for LIONEL MESSI
: 10000000
New employee LIONEL
MESSI with employee ID 10 has been enrolled, welcome to hell! You have been paid as low as $ 10000000
Total number of employees created = 0
```

Comment: You're using "puts", which appends a newline.

Comment: In answer to #2, you probably want to define the getCount as a class method, not an instance method.  You'd then call Employee.getCount, rather than calling getCount on an instance.

Comment: Yes, that can be done, but I was trying to access Employee.@@employeeCount which used to throw error. Is this wrong way of accessing a static variable?

Comment: Yes. Have you considered reading some Ruby docs/tutorials? Searching for this provides answers.

Comment: @Raj "Static" is not a valid term in Ruby, variables that begin with `@@` are called *class variables*.

Comment: Yes @DaveNewton I always do my homework before posting here (well couldnt easily makeout my mistake in the first question though :P) I have checked in Ruby documents with me, none of them speak about directly accessing the class variables, neither about stripping. I googled for a while without success.

Comment: @Raj Searching for "ruby static variables": [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416372/static-variables-in-ruby), searching for "ruby class variables": [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084490/ruby-class-variables). Not sure how those didn't show up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newlines are from the user input. When the user types something and terminates the input with a newline (enter key) the newline is seen as part of the input. You can strip it off with the `String#strip()` method:

```
empName = empName.strip
```

or use the in-place method:

```
empName.strip!
```

To retrieve the value of the class variable you need a static getter (note the `self.`):

```
def self.getCount
    return @@employeeCount
end
```

Alternatively you can you the [class_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get) method.

Comment: Looks like 'class_variable_get' is a private method and Ruby doesnt respond to it. But yes, static method is an option, though I was still curious of how to access the class variables directly.

Comment: I get this: 'private method `class_variable_get' called for Employee:Class (NoMethodError)'

Comment: You have to call it like this: `Employee.class_variable_get(:@@employeeCount)` (it just worked for me)

Comment: I did the same and still getting the error. Looks like it is deprecated in higher versions of Ruby. I am using ruby-1.9.3-p125 version.

Comment: `$ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_DESCRIPTION
=> "ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]"
irb(main):002:0> class Employee; @@employeeCount = 42; end
=> 42
irb(main):003:0> Employee.class_variable_get(:@@employeeCount)
=> 42
`

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1: *Why constructor without any arguments are not called in Ruby?*

You wrote `def initiaze()`. Correct would be `def initialize()`:

```
def initialize()
    @@employeeCount += 1
    puts ("Initialize called!")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. as you seem to have noticed you misspelled `initialize` when
   defining the method
2. you can't reference the class variable directly
   outside the class, but you can make class or instance accessors for it, or use
   [Module#class_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get): `Employee.class_variable_get(:@@employeeCount)`
3. `gets` returns the whole line the user inputs, including the terminating newline. Another answer recommended [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) but this removes all trailing and leading whitespace. If you just want to remove the newline, use [String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp), `empName = empName.chomp!` Be careful if you're tempted to apply chomp directly to gets as gets will return nil at end of file and you'll raise NoMethodError sending :chomp to nil

BTW, your camelCasedNames are not good ruby style. Constants should be all UPPER_CASE, except class and module names which should be CamelCased with leading cap, all other names should be lower_case_with_underscores_to_separate_words. Also, in ruby, one generally omits the empty parens on argumentless method calls and definitions.