# Execute code in included module in class on load (not on initialize)

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a project where multiple classes will include `MyModule`. Upon including the module, I would like the classes that include the module to push a handle to the class type to a specific class-level array.

Psuedocode I've tried below that isn't having the effect I want:

```
class Poly
  @@tracking = []
end

module MyModule
  def initialize(klass)
    Poly.tracking << self # Where `self` is the class, e.g. `MyClass1`, not an instance of the class.
  end
end

class MyClass1
  include MyModule
end

class MyClass2
  include MyModule
end
```

When this is loaded, I'd like for `Poly.tracking` to equal `[MyClass1, MyClass2]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.  Use a [class instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable) instead of a class variable. Add an [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-included) method, which is run as a callback when a module is included into the class:

```
class Poly
  def self.tracking
    @tracking ||= []
  end
end

module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    Poly.tracking << base
  end
end

class MyClass1
  include MyModule
end

class MyClass2
  include MyModule
end

puts Poly.tracking.inspect #=> [MyClass1, MyClass2]
```

Comment: Very succinct. My understanding of instance variables in ruby is clearly lacking, that doesn't fit with how I understood they worked (mainly coming from a rails perspective). Thanks for the link, I'm going to go through that until I understand where I've gone wrong.