# How to run stored block?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that stores blocks, and I would like to run a block later. How can I run it?

```
class StoreBlocks
  @@blockarray = []
  def initialize
    @storedblock = yield
    @@blockarray << self
  end
  attr_reader :storedblock
  def self.getblock
    @@blockarray
  end
end

StoreBlocks.new do
  # cool codey stuff
end

# do other things
```

How would I run `StoreBlocks.getblock[0].storedblock`?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored blocks"? Blocks aren't objects, you can't store them. And what do you mean by "run `StoreBlocks.getBlock[0]`? Also, what's the purpose of dereferencing `@@blockarray` but completely ignoring its value on line 2? That's just a no-op and will probably be eliminated by a good optimizing compiler anyway.

Comment: Line 2 was a typo I have corrected it, and if I am not storing a block, what is `StoreBlocks.getblock[0].storedblock`?

Comment: On line 4, you are `yield`ing to the block and storing its return value in `@storedblock`.

Comment: I don't see reason to downvote, OP probably could do more research himself, but this is legitimate question for me.

Comment: Class instance variables (e.g., `@blockarray = []`) are generally preferred to class variables. Some Rubiests would never use a class variable. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable) a good discussion of the differences.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, thats really interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= yield` would assign the return value of passed block, not the block itself. You would need to change your class to something like this:

```
class StoreBlocks
  attr_accessor :storedblock
  @@blockarray
  def initialize &block
    @storedblock = block
    @@blockarray << self
  end
  def self.getblock
    @@blockarray
  end
end
```

`&` means that block passed to `initialize` will be converted to `Proc` and assigned to argument named `block`, and than you can store it in instance variable. You could than call it like:

```
StoreBlocks.getblock[0].storedblock.call()
```

Comment: Could be a reader, yes, if you don't want to assign it anymore. When I wrote the answer there wasn't any in your code, so I just wanted to remind you.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` will imediately call the block passed to initalize. This means that `@storeblock` will contain the result of calling `yield` not the block itself. FYI, you are not putting `@storedblock` into `@@blockarray`

If you want to store a block you can do something like this -

```
class BlockStore
  def initialize
    @blocks ||= []
  end

  def add_block(&block)
    @blocks << block
  end

  def run_all_blocks
    @blocks.each do |block|
      block.call
    end
  end
end

block_store = BlockStore.new
block_store.add_block do
  puts 'Hello!'
end
block_store.add_block do
  puts 'World!'
end
puts 'About to run all blocks'
block_store.run_all_blocks
```

This gives you an output like the below. I've output 'About to run all blocks' before running the blocks to show that they are stored and then run later -

```
➜  ruby blocks.rb 
About to run all blocks
Hello!
World!
```

Comment: The two answers were very similar, but @Borsunho was first