# Set class variable from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I want to have separate logs for my app. I created the following module:

```
module MyApp
  module MyLog
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def logger
        @@logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{self.name.underscore}.log")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in any of my models, I can add:

```
include MyApp::MyLog
```

and use it as (log file will appear in `.../log/cat.log`):

```
Cat.logger.info 'test'
```

I tried to use this method `included` on `Cat` and `Dog` models, and I have this result:

```
Cat.new.logger
# => #<Logger:0x007fe4516cf0b0 @progname=nil, ... @dev=#<File:/.../log/cat.log>, ... 
Dog.new.logger
# => #<Logger:0x007fe4516cf0b0 @progname=nil, ... @dev=#<File:/.../log/cat.log>, ... (the same)
```

If I try to use my logger for `Dog` model first, I will have a log file with the name `dog` (`/dog.log`).

How can I set class variable `@@logger` from a module for each class with the correct initialized logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use class variable, use `instance_variable` that is attached to the class.

```
module MyApp
  module MyLog

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def logger
        @logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{self.name.underscore}.log")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

## Example:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def logger
      puts @logger
      @logger ||= name
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

class C
  include A
end

B.logger
#
B.logger
# B
C.logger
#
B.logger
# B
C.logger
# C
```

First time you call the method it is `nil`, thus the empty line, second time you call method the value equals to class name, `B`, and if called on new class it is again `nil`, check also this answer

[Ruby class instance variable vs. class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable)