# Increment counter on page hit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have this so far. I want to increment the counter every time a GET request is sent to counter#add. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CounterController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def home
  end

  def add
    @counter += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every get request is a NEW instance of `CounterController`, so it's always starting at zero. This is why whenever you create an instance variable like `@post` it's not there on the next request.  `@counter` is just another example of that.

An alternative might be to make it a class instance...

```
class CounterController < ApplicationController

  @counter = 0

  def self.add
    @counter += 1
  end

  def self.counter
    @counter
  end

  def home
  end

  def add
    class.add
  end

  def show_counter
    class.counter
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I followed your example and changed some things.

Comment: In ruby @@variable_name is used for class variable and @variable_name is used for instance variable name.

Comment: @c0de222 except that every class is an instance of a superclass and can therefore have its own instance variables, referred to as class instance variables.  This answer explains it well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15773671/2516474