# Ruby Access Class Variables Easily

Tags: ruby, class

I've created a class that I'm using to store configuration data. Currently the class looks like this:

```
class Configed
    @@username = "test@gmail.com"
    @@password = "password"
    @@startpage = "http://www.example.com/login"
    @@nextpage = "http://www.example.com/product"
    @@loginfield = "username"
    @@passwordfield = "password"
    @@parser = "button"
    @@testpage = "http://www.example.com/product/1"
    @@button1 = "button1"
    def self.username
        @@username
    end
    def self.password
        @@password
    end
    def self.startpage
        @@startpage
    end
    def self.nextpage
        @@nextpage
    end
    def self.loginfield
        @@loginfield
    end
    def self.passwordfield
        @@passwordfield
    end
    def self.parser
        @@parser
    end
    def self.testpage
        @@testpage
    end
    def self.button1
        @@button1
    end
end
```

To access the variables I'm using:

```
# Config file
require_relative 'Configed'

# Parse config
startpage = Configed.startpage
loginfield = Configed.loginfield
passwordfield = Configed.passwordfield
username = Configed.username
password = Configed.password
nextpage = Configed.nextpage
parser = Configed.parser
testpage = Configed.testpage
```

This is not very modular. Adding additional configuration data needs to be referenced in three places.

**Is there a better way of accomplishing this?**

Comment: Use OpenStruct instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make class level instance variables...

```
class Configed
  @username = "test@gmail.com"
  @password = "password"
  @startpage = "http://www.example.com/login"
  # ...
  class << self
    attr_reader :username, :password, :startpage # ...
  end
end
```

It's somewhat more compact, and still gives you

```
username = Configed.username
# ...
```

NOTE: there's a lot of good ideas in @philomory 's answer that deserves consideration.  The use of YAML in particular would allow you to set up different constants for different environemnts `test`, `development`, `production` etc, and you can load the current environment's configuration options into an OpenStruct created in an initializer.  Makes for a more flexible solution.

Comment: Note that to really match what he's already written in terms of behavior, you'd have to use `attr_reader`, not `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of potential improvements. First of all, no reason to use class variables if you don't want their [weird specific inheritance-related behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable), and no reason to use a class at all if you're not going to instantiate it.

You could use a module:

```
module Configed
  module_function
  def username
    'username'
  end
  # etc
end

Configed.username
```

But frankly, you're almost certainly better off using a hash:

```
Config = {
  username: 'username'
  # etc
}.freeze

Config[:username]
```

or, if you prefer method-style access, an [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'openstruct' # from standard library
Config = OpenStruct.new(
  username: 'username'
  # etc
).freeze

Config.username
```

If they need to be modifiable, just don't `freeze` them. Also, typically a constant which is not a class or a module (such as a hash) would have a name in ALL_CAPS, e.g. `CONFIGED`, but, that's a stylistic decision with no actual impact on the code.

Your question refers to 'parsing' the config, but of course, you're not; the config data in your setup (and in my examples so far) is just Ruby code. If you'd rather load it from a non-code file, there's always YAML:

config.yaml:

```
username: username
password: password
```

config.rb:

```
require 'yaml' # from Standard Library
Configed = YAML.load_file('config.yaml')
Configed['username']
```

or JSON:

config.json:

```
{
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password"
}
```

config.rb:

```
require 'json' # from Standard Library
Configed = JSON.parse(File.read('config.json'))
Configed['username']
```

Comment: Good answer, I'm referencing it in my own answer.