# Stripping and pushing strings into an array

Tags: ruby

I am running my program locally through my bin folder; this is just a small CLI project. I am trying to strip and push strings into an array.

Here is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

module BestPlaces
  class Places
    attr_accessor :name, :population, :places

      def initialize
        @places = []
      end

      def self.scrape_places
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://nomadlist.com/best-cities-to-live"))
        places = doc.search("div.text h2.itemName")
        ranks = doc.search("div.rank")
        places.each{|e| @places << e.text.strip}

          @places.each do |place|
            i = @places.index(place)
          puts "#{ranks[i].text}. #{place}"
        end
      end
    end

     class CLI
       def list_places
         puts "Welcome to the best places on Earth!"
         BestPlaces::Places.scrape_places
       end

       def call
         list_places
         menu
         goodbye
       end
     end
  end
```

When I run my program, I get an error:

```
block in scrape_places': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you got `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass`, because you are try manipulate an  **class instance variable** `@places` and it's value is `nil`.

The first one `@places` in method `initialize` is an object instance variable, you set its value to `[]`, but the second one `@places` in class method `self.scrape_places` is a class instance variable, you did't give any value to it, so it's  nil by default. Notice the **two variable are not the same**. Since you supposed they are the same, so you may want change `def self.scrape_places` to `def scrape_places`, then they will be the same object instance variable.

see also:

[Ruby class instance variable vs. class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and article!