# Ruby class variable scope issue

Tags: ruby, variables, scope, class-instance-variables

Ok, so I've read up on class variables, class instance variables and instance variables in Ruby. I found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable) by Phrogz very illuminating.

Now I'm trying to add a variable to my class that is accessible by multiple methods within my class, but that is not shared among multiple instances of the class:

```
Class QuizSession < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :index_changed
  def initialize
    @index_changed = false
  end

  def index_changed?
    @index_changed
  end

  def set_index_changed!
    @index_changed = false
  end

  def method_a
    do sth.
    ...
    @index_changed = true
  end
end
```

What I want is this:  *(like `@my_things` in [Phrogz example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable))*

```
session_a = QuizSession.new
session_b = QuizSession.new

session_a.method_a

p session_a.index_changed? #=> true
p session_b.index_changed? #=> false
```

Am I assuming correctly, that currently I'm defining 4 different `@index_changed` variables, each in the scope of their respective method, but not visible to the rest of the class?

But if I declare the `@index_changed` variable outside of a method as a class instance variable, won't it be shared among class instances as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I assuming correctly, that currently I'm defining 4 different `@index_changed` variables, each in the scope of their respective method, but not visible to the rest of the class?

No.

`@index_changed` is an **instance variable**. It is an attribute of each instance of the class.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :my_instance_var
  def initialize(val)
    @my_instance_var = val
  end
end

f1 = Foo.new(true)
f2 = Foo.new(false)

f1.my_instance_var # => true
f2.my_instance_var # => false
```

> But if I declare the `@index_changed` variable outside of a method as a class instance variable, won't it be shared among class instances as well?

Yes, because in that case you would be declaring a **class** instance variable. This is different.

---

To clarify, your code above is declaring a variable that is "owned by the class instance". So it is accessible *within all of the methods*, but is not shared between different class instances.

A class variable, on the other hand, is "*owned by the class*". So, if you like, it is "shared between all instances".

Comment: Thank you @Tom that aswers my question. Now I know my problem lies somewhere else! :)