# Class variables being overwritten with inheritance

Tags: ruby

I have class factory which looks like this:

```
class Base

  def self.attributes=(**keyvals)
    attr_accessor *@@attributes.keys
    define_singleton_method(:default) { new(**keyvals) }
  end

  def self.attributes
    @@attributes
  end

  def initialize(opts={})
    opts.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end

end
```

Usage looks like this:

```
# the game
class Game < Base
  self.attributes = {
    players: {} # Hash of Player instances, keyed by name
  }
end

print Game.default.instance_variables
# => [:@player]

# a single tile
class Tile < Base
  self.attributes = {
    type: '',
    data: {}
  }
end

print Tile.default.instance_variables
# => [:@type, :@data]

# -----------------
# PROBLEM IS HERE:
# -----------------

print Game.default.instance_variables
# => [:@type, :@data]
```

The problem is that `Game.attributes` is being overwritten when I define `Tile.attributes`. I was expecting that the class instance variable set from `Tile` would be unique to `Tile`, but apparently this is not the case.

Is there a way to change class instance variables of a single descendent using an inherited method? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `@@var` is a class variable, whereas `@var` (within the scope of the class) is a class **instance** variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15773552/477037

Comment: @Stefan sorry, i got my terminology wrong. I'm meaning to use a class variable.

Comment: Class variables don't work well with inheritance (did you read the linked question?). They are often considered a code smell: https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Class-Variable.md