# Not a class variable, but maybe an instance variable -- but on what?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand what type of variable `@bar` is, in the code below.

```rb
class Foo
  @bar = 7       # defined outside of initialize method

  def self.bar   # defined on the class, not as an instance method
    @bar
  end
end
```

- It uses the single `@` notation, which makes it an instance variable
- But because it's defined outside of an `initialize` method, I think it becomes an instance variable on the `Foo` class, *not* an instance variable on *instances* of `Foo`

If ^^^ is correct, then I guess I just want to understand the possible uses of this. I was doing something like this recently in order to memoize something similar to the following:

```rb
class FileCache
  @cache = {}
  def self.read(filename)
    @cache[filename] ||= File.read(filename)
  end
end
```

The intention of the `FileCache::read` method is prevent going out to the file system every time you want to read a given file. It seems to work with `@cache` defined on the class (rather than via `attr_reader` or inside of `initialize`), and I just want to make sure I understand why.

It seems like what's happening is that `@cache` becomes an *instance variable of the Singleton object* `FileCache`, which itself is an instance of the `Class` class.

Is ^^^ anywhere near a correct understanding? I've also tried reading [this artcile](https://medium.com/rubycademy/understanding-the-eigenclass-in-less-than-5-minutes-dcb8ca223eb4). Looking for someone who knows to confirm/deny my understanding.

Comment: Have you see this question, I found the discussion there very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable