# Ruby variable not accessible in classes

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable to numerous classes but get an 'undefined local variable or method' error.

I've created a 'Player' class which has a method to initialise an object with two parameters, and have a 'Board' class where I want to use one of these parameters (I've just included a 'puts' statement for simplicity below) but this is where the error occurs.  Outside of the 'Board' class, the same statement works (currently commented out).

How can I use the player1.name value inside of the 'Board' class please?  Thanks

```
class Player
attr_accessor :name, :symbol

  def initialize(name, symbol)
    @name = name
    @symbol = symbol
  end

end 


class Board

puts player1.name

end

player1 = Player.new("Player1","X")
#puts player1.name
```

Comment: did you initialize `player` object in `Board` class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to call the instance of `player1` inside the `Board` class before it is created.

This means `player1` does not exist in that context.

I guess you could either instantiate it inside the `Board` class or pass it as an option. Here's an example:

```
class Board
  def initialize(options={})
    # Uses the player passed to it.
    @player = options[:player]
  end

  # Not often seen since you can get it from the player class
  # but can be done here inside the Board class too if you want to.
  def player_name
    puts @player.name
  end

end

# Instantiate your player as usual.
player1 = Player.new("Player1","X")

# Adding it to an options hash
# this step is optional, you can add it directly to board
# like you did for adding the name and symbol to the player class.
options = {player: player1}

# Instantiate a board with the player you've created.
board = Board.new(options)

# To puts the player name run the method.
board.player_name # "Player1"
```

See [Ruby Classes and Modules](https://github.com/csalmeida/ruby-classes-and-modules) if you would like more examples and learn more.

Comment: Note that `puts @player.name` will always result in `NoMethodError: undefined method \`name' for nil:NilClass`. `@player` in the `initialize` method is another variable than `@player` in class context. The former `@player` is the instance variable of an instance variable `Board`. While the latter `@player` is an instance variable of the class `Board`, which people also call a [class instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable).

Comment: That's correct but thought this would give @Turbo124 enough to go on as I'm not sure what is trying to be achieved here. However, I've edited the answer to expand on the example. Wrapped the `puts` statement in a method and added how to use it in the end. Hopefully this helps! Thanks @3limin4t0r

Answer (score 0):

When you open a class with the `class` keyword you open a new scope and the current bindings are thrown out of the window. Furthermore your code would never work since you reference `player1` before defining the variable.

To solve these two issues we have to move the `player1` definition above the class. Then instead of using the `class` keyword to define `Board` class we can use the [`Class` constructor](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Class.html#method-c-new) which keeps the current bindings.

This results in:

```
player1 = Player.new("Player1","X")

Board = Class.new do
  puts player1.name
end
```

Although this might solve your problem, I doubt that this is the functionality you'll actually need. The question reeks of a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The above will bind the class as a whole to what the `player1` value is at the moment of class definition.

In turn this means that every instance of `Board` is in some way bound to `player1`. I assume that every instance of `Board` can have its own player(s), in which case the following would be a better fit:

```
class Board
  def initialize(player1)
    @player1 = player1
  end
end
```