# Why am I getting NoMethodError undefined method for nil::NilClass

Tags: ruby

```
['board'].each{|script| require_relative script}

class GameRunner

    @board = Board.new

    def initialize
    end

    def getBoard
        @board
    end

end
```

This piece of code generates an error when `getBoard` is called. But when I move the instantiation of `@board` to the `initialize` block there is no errors. Why?

Edit: An answer with a more clear explanation on what is going on: [Ruby class instance variable vs. class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable)

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: @SenaYevenyo : You referenced the instance variable `@board`, but did not define it anywhere. If you want it to be an instance variable, you could set it to some value inside `initialize`,  or add `attr_accessor :board` to your class.  If you want to use the class variable `@board`, you must make `getBoard` a class method, i.e. `def self.getBoard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `@board` is a class variable, not an instance variable.

What you probably mean is:

```rb
class GameRunner
  # Anything declared here is assumed to be class-level

  def initialize
    # Anything inside an instance method is an instance variable
    @board = Board.new
  end

  def getBoard
    @board
  end
end
```

Since classes are objects, the class can also have its own instance variables. Confusingly they also use the same `@` prefix.

It's worth noting that accessors like this are usually declared in Ruby as:

```rb
attr_reader :board
```

Which makes the method for you. The `get` prefix is almost always omitted because mutator methods (e.g. `set`) are the same but with the `=` suffix.

Comment: Note for OP's code: `@board` defined inside class is an instance variable of `class GameRunner`, where `GameRunner` is an instance of `class Class`. That's another different concept.

Comment: @iBug It can get real confusing in a hurry to go down that rabbit hole, so left it with a very superficial explanation.

Comment: Sure, but don't class level properties begin with '@@' instead of '@'? When I do replace '@board' with '@@board' in the script in the original question, there are no errors. I am trying to define an instance variable which I would like to make it private using the private keyword.

Comment: Those are different in scope as the class *and* the instances can see those, and every instance uses the same `@@board`. They're also a lot more tricky to use effectively as they get shared far, far more broadly. Do you need an instance of that board per "runner", or do all runners share exactly the same board? Normally that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here `@board` is an *instance variable*. Instance variables belong to an object (instance), hence why they are called *instance* variables.

You have two references to an instance variable named `@board` in your code. Now, ask yourself: *which object* do they belong to? In other words: what is `self` at the point where you reference the instance variable?

```ruby
class GameRunner
  # Here, `self` is `GameRunner`
  @board = Board.new

  def getBoard
    # Here, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`
    @board
  end
end
```

At the first reference to `@board`, `self` is the `GameRunner` class itself. Remember, class are objects just like any other object; they are instances of the `Class` class just like strings are instances of the `String` class, integers are instances of the `Integer` class, and game runners are instances of the `GameRunner` class.

You can easily see that the instance variable has been defined and initialized:

```ruby
GameRunner.instance_variables
#=> [:@board]

GameRunner.instance_variable_get(:@board)
#=> #<Board:0x0000deadbeef1230>
```

At your second mention, however, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`, and *not* the `GameRunner` class itself.

Or, to put it differently: you have *two completely independent* instance variables of *two completely independent objects*. The instance variables just happen to have the same name.

It's *exactly* the same as if you did:

```ruby
game_runner1 = GameRunner.new
game_runner2 = GameRunner.new
```

The instance variables of `game_runner1` and `game_runner2` are private to each of those two objects. `game_runner1` does not know anything about the instance variables of `game_runner2` and vice versa. The same thing is true about `game_runner1` and `GameRunner`.

Again, it is important to remember that classes are just objects like any other object.

It looks like what you actually want is to have both references refer to the same instance variable, namely an instance variable of an instance of `GameRunner`. You can achieve that by moving the assignment into an instance method, something like this:

```ruby
class GameRunner
  def initializeBoard
    # Here, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`
    @board = Board.new
  end

  def getBoard
    # Here, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`
    @board
  end
end
```

However, this is somewhat annoying because you always have to remember to call `initializeBoard` before you can use the object, and you have to make sure that once you have called `initializeBoard`, you never call it again.

To make initialization tasks like this easier, Ruby has a convention: the default implementation of `Class#new` will call a method named `initialize` on the newly allocated object:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(...)
    obj
  end
end
```

[This is not quite accurate because `initialize` is private by default, so it would be more like `obj.__send__(:initialize, ...)`, but you get the idea.]

So, if we simply rename the `initializeBoard` method to `initialize`, that will ensure that our instance variable is always initialized by `GameRunner::new`:

```ruby
class GameRunner
  def initialize
    # Here, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`
    @board = Board.new
  end

  def getBoard
    # Here, `self` is an *instance* of `GameRunner`
    @board
  end
end
```

Note that your code violates multiple Ruby community coding standards:

- Ruby uses 2 spaces for indentation, not 4.
- There should be no empty line after `class` or before `end`
- Method names use `snake_case`, not `camelCase`. IOW, your getter method should be called `get_board`.
- … Except it shouldn't, because getters should simply be called `noun`, not `get_noun`, i.e. your getter method should be called simply `board`.
- Lastly, trivial getters should not be defined by hand, but using the core `Module#attr_reader` method.

If we combine all of this, your class should look like this:

```ruby
class GameRunner
  attr_reader :board

  def initialize
    @board = Board.new
  end
end
```

I, personally, prefer to avoid referring to instance variables directly as much as possible, and only use getters and setters. However, that is not a majority coding style, that is just my personal preference:

```ruby
class GameRunner
  attr_reader :board

  private

  def initialize
    self.board = Board.new
  end

  attr_writer :board
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but not really answering what I was interested in. Apparently I assumed that Ruby instance variable declaration/instantiation was similar to Java. In this case '@@' referred to 'static' and a single '@' referred to instance variables. Apparently that was not the case as explained in the comments in the answer below and hence has been accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. Variables that start with `@` are indeed instance variables. They are just like instance fields in Java, except for the fact that they are always private. I am not sure what you mean by 'static' variables. Ruby doesn't have static variables. Also, I am not sure what you mean by "instance variable declaration/instantiation". There are no variable declarations in Ruby. Also, note that the accepted answer is wrong: it claims that `@board` is a class variable, but it is not. It is an instance variable. Class variables start with `@@`.

Comment: In Java and C++ you can initialize member variables with defaults but it's done at what in Ruby is at the class level. In Ruby that's the wrong context. Conflicting declaration styles here for anyone that's familiar with the other kind.

Comment: @JörgWMittag A similar question with its explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable

I believe my question can be deleted or left over for reference