# How can I lock class variable in ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```rb
class Test
  def self.states
    @@states ||= OpenStruct.new({initial: 'initial', started: 'started'}).freeze
  end
end
```

1. Does above code mean `@@states` is frozen ?
2. Is `@@states` re-assignable then how?
3. Is writing `@states` and `@@states` same in class methods ?
4. If `@@states` is not-frozen or re-assignable then how can I lock `@@states` once it is set so that it is not re-assignable?

Comment: You freeze objects, not variables. Freezing an object prevents modifications of that object. Variables referring to that object aren't affected at all and can be re-assigned just like before.

Comment: BTW, you probably want `@state` which is – in that context – a so-called _class instance variable_. You prevent modifications of the variable by not exposing it to the outside, e.g. by not having a setter method. Alternatively use a constant which prints a warning when being re-assigned.

Comment: If you have 4 questions, please ask 4 questions, not one question. Thank you very much for keeping [so] clean and lean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does above code mean `@@states` is frozen?

Yes (sort-of). You called `.freeze` on the object, so the object is frozen. I.e. *technically* the "frozen" thing is the object referenced by the variable, not the variable itself:

```
[1] pry(main)> x = "hello".freeze
=> "hello"
[2] pry(main)> x.frozen?
=> true
[3] pry(main)> x = "world"
=> "world"
[4] pry(main)> x.frozen?
=> false
```

> Is `@@states` re-assignable then how?

There's no "public interface" to change the variable, but you can do it via meta-programming:

```
Test.class_variable_set('@@states', 'CHANGED!')
```

> Is writing `@states` and `@@states` same in class methods?

No. There's a subtle difference between an *instance variable in a class* and a *class variable.* For example, [see this answer for a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773671/1954610).

> If `@@states` is not-frozen or re-assignable then how can I lock @@states once it is set so that it is not re-assignable?

You can't make it *impossible* to change/reassign anything in ruby; the best you can do is make it *very awkward* -- i.e. you have to write something "hacky" to change it.

In other words, you can remove any "public interface" and make the object frozen (which is exactly what you've done already), but - by the nature of ruby being a dynamic language with powerful meta-programming - there's always going to be some back-door way of changing a variable if you're really determined. For instance, see [this library.](https://github.com/zizkovrb/melt)

This isn't unique to ruby -- for example, [it's possible to *change constants* in C/C++ by using pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-modify-a-const-variable-in-c).

Comment: This is an excellent explanation but I think I have one tiny nitpick. What's frozen is the instance of `OpenStruct` that's assigned to `@@states`. That instance can't be modified, but `@@states` can be reassigned. You explain it further down but I'd make it clear upfront.

Comment: There is also the gotcha with class variables that even if your class doesn't expose the class variable a subclass could and ruin the party for everyone. A class instance variable would be a better choice.

Comment: @max Sure -- and you could also dynamically extend the class to define your own setter! There's probably lots of ways that you *could* change the variable via some "back door", but given the currently shared code there's no "front door" way of changing it.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord and ALL, for sharing the insights.