How to access class attribute, which was set by class_exec()
This is what I'm trying to do:
class Foo; end

Foo.class_exec do
  class_variable_set(:@@x, 42)
  def get
    @@x # runtime error here!
  end
end

puts Foo.new.get

I'm getting (Ruby 3.2.1):
$ ruby a.rb
a.rb:6:in `get': class variable access from toplevel (RuntimeError)
    from a.rb:10:in `<main>'

How can I read this @@x, which I just set?

There's class_variable_get, but since it's a method of Module, you have to call it on the receiver's class or singleton_class:
Foo.class_exec do
  class_variable_set(:@@x, 42)
  def get
    self.class.class_variable_get(:@@x)
    # or
    # singleton_class_variable_get(:@@x)
  end
end

Alternatively, it's perfectly fine in Ruby to re-open a class:
class Foo; end

class Foo
  @@x = 42

  def get
    @@x
  end
end

Note that it's usually discouraged to use class variables, due to their unexpected inheritance behavior see Why is using a class variable in Ruby considered a 'code smell'?

so using @@x just ignores the class_exec context. would that be a bug?

@Alex it's just like Foo.class_exec { Bar = 123 } which sets a top level constant Bar instead of Foo::Bar.

that makes so much sense now. it explains class variable behavior better than comparing them to instance variables: explains inheritance, why they're available from instance and class methods, even explains why it's a code smell (using constants as variables). perhaps worth an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable

@Alex quite a few similarities, but there are also differences. Constants have lexical scope (nesting) whereas class variables have dynamic scope (inheritance).
