# How make a variable public final in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, immutability

I would like to create a class that during initialization of an Object of this class would assign provided value to one of the variables, in such way it can't be changed.
For example:

```
person = Person.new("Tom")
person.name  #=> Tom
person.name = "Bob"
```

this should raise an error or:

```
person.name #=> Tom -> still
```

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about "final" variables, which doesn't exist in Ruby. But take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441524/closest-ruby-representation-of-a-private-static-final-and-public-static-final

Comment: Why are you defining `name=` on Person in the first place if you don’t want it?

Comment: That was an example  in case someone tried to set it again and I'd like to prevent it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person
  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end
  attr_reader :name
end

person = Person.new("Tom")
person.name         #=> Tom
begin
  person.name = "Bob"
rescue
  puts $!.message   # => Undefined method error
end
person.name         #=> Tom
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you : [static variables in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416372/static-variables-in-ruby)

```
class Foo
 @@foos = 0

 def initialize
 @@foos += 1
 end

 def self.number_of_foos
 @@foos
 end
end

Foo.new
Foo.new
Foo.number_of_foos #=> 2
```