# Ruby Static Inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, static

I am trying to use a class variable in ruby.  But class variables change throughout the entire hierarchy, and thus are useless for this goal:

Assume I have 3 classes, each inherited, except the parent.

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

class C < B
end
```

How would I modify or create a static variable in the middle class so that class A does not have it but class C does.

```
B.num = 2

A.num # undefined or nil
C.num # 2
```

I should also specify that A.num should still be able to be used, without changing B.num or C.num, unless its inherited.

Comment: Why is a class variable "useless"? Your sentence does not logically follow.

Comment: @sawa I don't believe my sentence does not flow. A Class Variable on class B will change the class variable on class A as well.  It will change parents and children.  Please review this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251352/ruby-inherit-code-that-works-with-class-variables?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: You did not seem to understand my comment correctly. I am mentioning that the fact that class variables are shared among the hierarchy does not lead to your conclusion that class variables are useless. I am asking for the basis of your claim that class variables are useless.

Comment: That answer says @@variables are not class variables...

Comment: Obviously class variables are not useless.  They don't work as expected for my desired goal.

Comment: That makes sense, but you wrote that they are useless.

Comment: Here is another example of class variables used as global vars.
http://www.sitepoint.com/class-variables-a-ruby-gotcha/

Answer (score 3):

**Edited since the OP changed the question**

Use a class instance variable for `A` and `B`.

```
class A
  singleton_class.class_eval{attr_accessor :num}
end

class B < A
  singleton_class.class_eval{attr_accessor :num}
end

class C < B
  def self.num; superclass.num end
  def self.num= v; superclass.num = v end
end

B.num = 2
A.num # => nil
C.num # => 2
```

Comment: To add on to Sawa's answer: If you later decided that B should not override num, then you have to copy the definition of `self.num` from C into B.  Every class that has a `num` or delegates to its super class must still have a few lines of code for `num`.