# Why does using class_eval cause toplevel class variable to be set?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I wrote some code to learn about the class_eval method. My understanding is that Foo.class_eval will set self to "Foo" and evaluate the block below in that context, just as saying "class Foo" will do. However, the code below shows that setting a class variable using class_eval will assign the class variable at the toplevel: to "Object". Why does this happen?

```
class Foo
end

class Foo
  puts self
  # => Foo
  @@class_var = "hello"
end

puts Object.class_variables
# => []

Foo.class_eval do
    puts self
    # => Foo
    @@class_var = "hi"
    # => warning: class variable access from toplevel
end

puts Object.class_variables
# => @@class_var
```

Comment: If you use single `@` it should work correctly. See the first annswer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251352/ruby-inherit-code-that-works- with-class-variables

Comment: Using single @ does get rid of the warning, but I think that still doesn't answer my question: if self is Foo in the class_eval block, why does the class variable I set end up a class variable of Object?

Comment: all classes inherit from object, and double @ variables are shared with the whole inheritance chain. Like the answer I linked says, they're more like globals. Don't blame you for being confused.

Comment: Mhm. Double @ variables are shared down the inheritance chain. Object is above Foo in the chain, so I don't see why @@class_var belongs to Object.

Comment: i guess that's a good point, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments  a single `@` would do what you want, now if you were running the code from inside another class `@@` would work but it would set a class variable for  both Foo, and whatever class you running from:

```
class Foo
  puts self
  # => Foo
  @@class_var = "hello"
end

class Bar
  def self.main
    puts Object.class_variables
    # => []

    Foo.class_eval do
      puts self
      # => Foo
      @@class_var = "hi"
    end
  end
end

Bar.main
p [Bar.class_variables]
#[[:@@class_var]]
p [Foo.class_variables]
#[[:@@class_var]]
```

That has to do with `proc` or `block` scope, I was expecting it to set only `@@class_var` only on `Bar` class but it actually sets on both, weird.

Comment: This is illuminating, but I'm not sure it fully answers my question. It shows that when class_eval is called within a "class Bar" block, Bar gets the class variable. In my example, there's similar (but still confusing) behavior: class_eval is called within the context of "Object" (top-level class) and Object is assigned the class variable.

Comment: yeah there must be something special about context, if you think there  that's the entry-point of your app, so I assume that's some magic going on. if you rename Bar to Object it would still work just like monkey patch does

Comment: also if you run `p self` form the top level context you don't see `Object` but you see `main`